# JavaScript Variabl Scope

Tags: javascript, scope

The following piece of code will create a new webclient socket connection.  The issue I am having is how to get the scope of the socket opbject.

How do I get to reference the socket object within the init() function?

With the example below when doing this.socket within the init() function it seems as it is creating a new socket object local to the init function.

```
    return webClient = {
        clientConnection: null,
        ioClient: null,
        socket: null,
        ready: false,
        init: function(callback){
            this.ioClient = require('socket.io-client');
            console.log('Web Config :');
            console.log(webClientConfig);
            this.socket = this.ioClient.connect(webClientConfig.connectionString, {'forceNew':true });
            this.socket.on('connect', function(){
                console.log('Web Client Connected');
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

In this context the this identifier refers to te webClient.

Comment: in `init` it may not be, depending on how init is called :p

Comment: e.g. if x is set to the value that is returned, `setTimeout(x.init, 0)`, `this` is the global object (window, or whatever in nodejs)

Comment: This is not a answer. Please add this as a comment.

Comment: it's an attempted answer @mrid :p

Answer (score 0):

Declare globally a variable to get websocket connection, like

```
var webSocket = require('socket.io-client');
```

Then you can use webSocket variable anywhere. like

```
return webClient = {
        clientConnection: null,
        ioClient: null,
        socket: null,
        ready: false,
        init: function(callback){
            this.ioClient = webSocket;
            console.log('Web Config :');
            console.log(webClientConfig);
            this.socket = this.ioClient.connect(webClientConfig.connectionString, {'forceNew':true });
            this.socket.on('connect', function(){
                console.log('Web Client Connected');
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting (and not seeing) `this` as `webClient` in `webClient.init` - you can simply do this

```
var webClient = {
    clientConnection: null,
    ioClient: null,
    socket: null,
    ready: false,
    init: function(callback){
        webClient.ioClient = require('socket.io-client');
        console.log('Web Config :');
        console.log(webClientConfig);
        webClient.socket = this.ioClient.connect(webClientConfig.connectionString, {'forceNew':true });
        webClient.socket.on('connect', function(){
            console.log('Web Client Connected');
    });
};
return webClient;
```

though, I'd have the `require('socket.io-client');` as a global

```
const ioClient = require('socket.io-client');
//
// 
//
var webClient = {
    clientConnection: null,
    ioClient: null,
    socket: null,
    ready: false,
    init: function(callback){
        webClient.ioClient = ioClient;
        console.log('Web Config :');
        console.log(webClientConfig);
        webClient.socket = this.ioClient.connect(webClientConfig.connectionString, {'forceNew':true });
        webClient.socket.on('connect', function(){
            console.log('Web Client Connected');
    });
};
return webClient;
```